# InfoPath Designer 2010 Error in Forms Code

Tags: 2010, infopath

I have an issue that I need assistance with. I did not create nor develop the InfoPath form and I am still getting familiar with using this software as well. I have a user who reported an issue with the form. Below is a snapshot of part of the form where the user can either choose Yes or No:

[image]

Once a selection has been made, a dialog box should open saying something like **Process Complete**. Instead, an error message pops up shown below:

[image]

I have checked Google and cannot find a solid answer to this solution. I have checked blogs and forums that have similar errors but nothing close to getting resolved. Can someone please assist in understanding this problem and fixing it?

NOTE: Even with full control or using different browsers does not fix issue.

Comment: I don't think that's your issue but dialog boxes are not supported on InfoPath forms when they run on a browser, they can only show up when you fill your form using InfoPath Filler.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a permissions issue. Does the user have Contribute permissions to the Form Library or List?

Comment: Even with Full Control or Farm Admin gets the same issue. Tried using different browsers and does not fix issue as well.

Comment: Hm...that is strange. Is this user the only one with the issue? Perhaps his User Profile has gotten corrupted?

Comment: This thread on infoPathDev.com has a few suggestions if it's only one user being affected: http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/p/17738/62474.aspx

Comment: Thanks JimShelley. That link you posted was actually the first thing I read when doing research about the issue but sadly does not fix the issue:( Would you happen to have any other suggestions??

Comment: I want to verify one thing: It's just this one user who is getting the error right? Other users can use the form still?Is that correct?

Comment: Okay, I found this link that suggests (if it is just the one user) that they may have a bad Office install: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a2e6f2ea-0bee-443e-9600-2fa2567d29e3/one-user-cant-access-infopath-form-template-on-sharepoint-list

Comment: Actually it's the other way around. Every user gets the error, including me, when opening form. One thing I can try is to republish the form to the Form Library but that is all I have.

Comment: Ah. That's very different. You could also publish it to a different (new) form library, but you would lose all the old data.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

1. checking the submit location if it is correct.
2. check button rules
3. The file/form is not opened by another user when accessing/editing it (multiple instance)

Also, try republishing if you do not find any issues on 1 to 3.